Identify a component labeled "RU" inside a Canon Vixia HG20 LCD display
I found this component inside a Canon Vixia HG20 LCD PCB:


This seems to be an opaque lens of some kind, so my first thought is that this could be an IR sender/receiver. Since there are 4 terminals, we could be looking at 2 diodes, despite the unusual 3 x 1 terminal disposition. Unfornunatelly, at this moment I can't test/measure it.
Notice that this opaque dome is pointing at the covered window on the second photo, so maybe it was used for testing during development.
Also, the component label caught my attention: RU200. Obviously, this has nothing to do with RU certification.
Any thoughts on what this component might be?

It looks more like the whole board is the RU200. The component designators are much smaller, as is "SW2".

The user manual says that location has the infrared remote receiver. And the looks match to an infrared receiver module.

That's right! I knew it had this feature, but I did not remember it was there!

It might mean "receiver unit"...
